# Database connections and bitmaps are managed or unmanaged resources?

Tags: c#

Confused:
cwick which asked [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538060/proper-use-of-the-idisposable-interface/538238#538238) states at his edit:
unmanaged resources such as database connections and bitmaps.

But in the code part of accepted answer:

```
//Free managed resources too
```

means freeing:

```
this.databaseConnection
this.frameBufferImage
```

So: database connections and bitmaps are managed or unmanaged resources?

Comment: Unmanaged.  But you never use an unmanaged resource directly, you use a friendly managed wrapper so you can use it in C#.  The code in the wrapper typically uses pinvoke to make unmanaged function calls.  One characteristic of such a wrapper is that it will have a Dispose() method and that it is important that you call it.

Answer (score 0):

They are **unmanaged** resources

> The most common types of unmanaged resource are objects that wrap operating system resources, such as files, windows, network connections, or database connections.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/unmanaged